# If I finish an activity and call it again, it's attribute values still remain inside thread (RunOnUiThread)

Tags: android

In this case, I have 2 activities. I'm on Activity 1 and go to Activity 2. The application works as intended.

The problem starts when I go back to Activity 1, and start Activity 2 again.

See code below:

```
public class ScreenWActivity extends SerialComActivity {

private static final String tag = "ScreenWActivity";    
private TextView mReception, m_tvDate, mtvPesoPercent, mtvState;
public String mCommand = null;
public int mActualProcess, mNextProcess;
private Commands mLastCommand;
public SettingsGlobal mSettings;
public int mAttempts = 0;
public long mStartTime, mTimeout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_W);

    this.mSettings = new SettingsGlobal(this); // get global settings
    this.mtvState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_state); // label to update the current state    

    startSerialConnection(); // open serial port and start connection. inherited from SerialComActivity (the upper class)
    this.mTimeout = 10; // timeout for commands response in seconds
    this.mNextProcess = 1; // the next step in the process, its updated in the stepN() methods
    this.mActualProcess = 1; // current step in the processo
    this.mLastCommand = Commands.OPEN_DOOR; // the last command I've sent, to know what to expect in return     
    this.executeWorkflow(mNextProcess); // starts the workflow
}

private void step1(){
    this.mtvState.setText("Closing door."); // update status
    this.writeSerial(Commands.OPEN_DOOR.command("080").getBytes()); // sends the command to the outputstream, the external device reads the command, execute it and respond back                
    this.mNextProcess = 2; // the next step in the process is 2
    this.mActualProcess = 1; // just tracking
    this.mLastCommand = Commands.OPEN_DOOR;
    startCounting(); // starts the timout, I've sent the command, now I wait for an answer
}

private void step2(){       
    this.mtvState.setText("Testando peso das balanças 1.");
    this.writeSerial(Commands.GET_W.command().getBytes()); // get weight from weighing-machine
    mLastCommand = Commands.GET_W; // the last command i sent i requested the weight - now I know what to expect
    mNextProcess = 3; // next step in the sequence in case everything goes according to plan
    this.mActualProcess = 2; // tracking    
    startCounting(); // starting timeout to get an answer
}

private void step3(){...}
private void step4(){...}
private void step5(){...}
private void step6(){...}

@Override
protected void writeSerial(byte[] buffer){...}

public void startCounting(){
    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
}

public void stopCounting(){
    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stopCounting();
    timerRunnable = null;
    if(this.mSerialPort != null)
        this.mSerialPort.close();

    this.mSerialPort = null;
    if(AppConfig.DEBUG) Log.i(tag, "finishing!");

    finish();
    super.onDestroy();      
}

public void executeWorkflow(int step) {
    switch(step){
    case 1:
        step1();
        break;
    case 2:
        step2();
        break;
    case 3:
        step3();
        break;
    case 4:
        step4();
        break;
    case 5:
        step5();
        break;
    case 6:
        step6();
        break;      
    }       
}

protected boolean validateReturn(String resposta) {         
    /// we check the command we've sent and the response we're given. if it matches, then we return true, else false        
}

// overrided from SerialComActivity, called when the external equipment sends a message to us
// ITS CALLED WHEN THERE IS INPUT FROM THE EXTERNAL EQUIPMENT
@Override
protected void onDataReceived(final byte[] buffer, final int size) {        
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            stopCounting(); // we remove the callbacks from the timeout thread          
            if( validateReturn(new String(buffer, 0, size).trim()) ){           // we check if the response is good     
                executeWorkflow(mNextProcess); // if its good, we move to the next step
            }else{
                mtvState.setText("invalid return"); // if not we message the user
                executeWorkflow(mActualProcess); // we try again
            }               
        }
    });
}

// RESPONSIBLE FOR THE TIMEOUT
// the code below was created intending to implement a timeout timer for waiting a response from the external device
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime;
        long seconds = (millis / 1000);         
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        if(mTimeout - seconds == 0 ){  
            mAttempts += 1;
            if(mAttempts == 3){ // we make 3 attempts to get a response, if it is the third, we quit trying and give error
                mAttempts = 0;
                mtvState.setText("Could not communicate.");
                stopCounting(); // we end the timer                 
            }else{              
                executeWorkflow(mActualProcess); // if we can still try, we send the command again                  
            }               
        }
    }
};
}
```

Inside the method `onDataReceived()`, which is called everytime I get a response from the external equipment, I use the attribute `mLastCommand` (which indicates the last command I've sent), so this way I know how to validate the response I get.

When I go back to Activity 2, in the class scope the values of the attributes are the same as the ones I've defined in the `onCreate()` method. In the LogCat I saw that the attributes values are correctly defined as stated in OnCreate.

BUT, when the method `onDataReceived` (it's inside a Thread in the `SerialComActivity` class) is called (which is called when I get data from outside) the value of this same attribute `mLastCommand` is the same as the first time I started the activity, regardless of the value I define for it. As if the the runnable inside `RunOnUiThread` is still holding the old values from the first time I entered the activity, and outside of it the class has the values I have defined.

It's like having two different attributes with the same name in the `ScreenWActivity`.

I tried nulling the attributes inside the `onDestroy()` method, but to no avail.

Below is the code for the `SerialComActivity` class:

```
public abstract class SerialComActivity extends Activity{

SerialPort mSerialPort = null;
protected OutputStream mOutputStream;
protected InputStream mInputStream;
protected ReadThread mReadThread;

private class ReadThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while(!isInterrupted()) {
            int size;
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
                if (mInputStream == null) return;
                size = mInputStream.read(buffer);
                if (size > 0) {
                    onDataReceived(buffer, size);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void startSerialConnection(){
    try {
        mSerialPort = new SerialPort(new File("/dev/ttyS2"), 38400, 0);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        if(AppConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.e("SERIAL", "portopen ERR: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        if(AppConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.e("SERIAL", "portopen ERR: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    mOutputStream = mSerialPort.getOutputStream();
    mInputStream = mSerialPort.getInputStream();
    /* Create a receiving thread */
    mReadThread = new ReadThread();
    mReadThread.start();    
}

protected abstract void onDataReceived(final byte[] buffer, final int size);
protected abstract void writeSerial(byte[] buffer);

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mReadThread != null){ 
        mReadThread.interrupt();
        if(AppConfig.DEBUG) Log.i("ThreadSerial", "interrupting");
    }
    if(mSerialPort != null)
        mSerialPort.close(); 
    mSerialPort = null;     
    finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

I'm still in the process of learning Java and Android programming, so please forgive me if I'm doing something wrong. I looked up around, and the thing that you can't use variables other than "final" inside the RunOnUiThred came up. But I think it's not the issue, since it works the first time I start the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a newbie in Java, but I think I found out what was happening. The thing is that I asked the wrong question.

The problem is in the `mInputStream.read()`. As I've come to know, it's a blocking operation. I'm creating a thread that stays blocked in that `read()` method. After I finish the `Activity`, (go back to the first one), the thread keeps running. I know that because when a send some information through the serial interface, that thread responds.

So what I did, and it's working for me, altough many people stated that this method is not recommended is use `mInputStream.available()`:

```
try {

    if (mInputStream == null){ Log.i(tag,"returning"); return null ;}
    Log.i(tag,"reading");
    mEmptyStream = true;
    while(mEmptyStream && !mFinish){
        Log.i(tag,"input while");
        /// checking if there is info, so we don't block the thread
        if(mInputStream.available() > 0){
            Log.i(tag,"input avail : " + InputStream.available());
            //stream not empty
            mEmptyStream = false;
            size = mInputStream.read(buffer); //
        }
    }

    if (size > 0) {
        Log.i(tag,"size > 0  = " + new String(buffer, 0, size));
        return new String(buffer,0,size);       
    }else{
        Log.i(tag,"size <= 0");
    }
}
```

Basically I loop using `available()`. When I finish the activity, in the `onPause()` method I set the field `mFinish` to true, this way the thread finds it's way out of execution and can end properly. It's the way I found and it's working so far. I improved the code significantly after the original post, like not running non UI jobs in the RunOnUiThread :)
But I tested it and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your clean up in `onPause()` instead of `onDestroy()`, `onDestroy()` may not be called immediately which means there may be a read conflict on `SerialPort`. Also if you are already in `onDestroy()`, calling `finish()` doesn't really do anything.

Lastly, for a finite resource like `SerialPort` connection, it's better to put it in a `Service`.

Comment: Hello Kai, thank you for taking the time to answer. I have created a `IntentService` in which I send the command and wait for a response. I tested it and I get response. But I need to set a timeout for it. Because when the code goes into the line `mInputStream.read(buffer)`, it blocks the execution until a response is obtained. So, I need to set a 15 second timeout and I don't know how to handle it. When I get the timeout, I should be able to stop/unregister the service and display an error in a text view. How can I implement the timeout? Thanks.